# How to route signals across to a breakoff tab?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I have a small circuit board that will be paneled with a breakoff tab that allows for easy handling during assembly.

Currently we just V-Score the square breakoff tab, but we're trying to find a way to route signals across the divider to a programming header on the tab. Is there a way to create a snap off tab that has about 8 thin signal traces routed across to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a method successfully used for break-away tabs with programming headers:

[image: Break-away Tabs]

The points of note are:

- Drilled holes for convenient break-away
- Traces are 10 mils, with a 6-mil neck at the break line: This provides a **natural strain point** on the copper trace, so it breaks cleanly right there.
- A corner on each trace, each side of the break-away holes. This ensures that even if a particular trace breaks badly, the **damage is constrained** to the immediate part of the trace up to the corner.

This has worked reliably for a bunch of boards, always broken by hand, not necessarily carefully.

Comment: +1. Could you please recommend a breakaway tab design?. Number of holes, dimensions, and distance between them?  I have seen several different design for that. Do you have any preference?

Comment: @JesúsCastañé That would depend on how many connections need to be routed, what other purpose the tab fulfils (*Mechanical hand-hold during assembly? Programming with pogo pins? Programming with header pins?*) and what the PCB material and thickness are. There's no one-size-fits-all, unfortunately.

Comment: How well would this work for internal signal layers?

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile Can't say first-hand, only needed it for double sided boards. It might be a challenge cleanly breaking a thicker, laminated multi-layer board.

Answer (score 2):

If you mill a number of small holes through the board instead of scoring it then you can route traces between the holes.

Comment: If I make the traces small (6mil or so) will I have any problems with dangling copper remnants using a method like this?

Comment: I would draw a knife across it before breaking in order to prevent problems.